# Pygame: Is it better to load an image multiple times, or keep a surface in memory?

Tags: python, pygame

Me and a friend are working on a game, and as part of the streamlining of code (we initially wrote it for a gamejam, that code is not neat at all :p ) he decided to set up the asset loader such that it loads sprites from a file each time they're requested.

This seems a bit heavy-handed to me. Isn't disk I/O going to be a big slowdown if we do that? Or am I worrying about nothing here? I haven't looked at his latest changes but I assume that he plans to later expand this to deal with sound effects and music as well.

The code is here: https://github.com/avivbeeri/GameJam

Any thoughts or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could post a relevant snippet of the code in your question, rather than just linking to Github.

Comment: Unless you are short on memory, just keep the surface around. However if you don't have that many assets, reloading from disk may hit the various caches and be very quick. Ymmv.

Comment: Memory access is quicker than disk access, so I would say memory unless you only have a very small amount of memory and can't.

Comment: As it turns out, the code to loads sprites from file the first time they're requested and then stores them in memory. I totally misunderstood my friend!
Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to keep the surface in memory. Reading in the image is a multi-step process that freezes the code while it's being run (unless you're threading, of course). I mean, unless you're keeping 500+ surfaces in memory, you're not really gonna run into a problem. But if you do get to the point of having 500+ images, the best solution would be to make an engine out of a lower level like C anyways.

**Short answer:** Loading the image every time it's used is slower and worse practice than just keeping it in memory.